# Adding custom widgets to QStackedWidget

Tags: qt, pyqt

I'm having difficulty adding a custom widget to a QStackedWidget. I want to include a widget with a different grid layout in this stacked widget.

If someone could show me how to set up the layout (buttons, etc.) inside the stacked widget, that would be even better. The main dialog containing the stacked widget is really simple, and I don't want to clutter it up with tonnes of grid just for one widget inside the stacked widget.

At the moment I'm trying to make the complex widget as a seperate class and insert an instance of this class into the stacked widget using `.addWidget()` (this doesn't work).

Maybe I'm thinking about it the wrong way?

I'm using PyQt, but C++ answers are acceptable — I can get an idea of how things work by looking at C++ (well, I've been fine so far =s).

Comment: Please close this question if You think its finished :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using QtCreator I suggest do it this way:

1. Design each page/widget as a seperate class (seperate *.cpp, *.h and *.ui files) - press ctrl+n and choose Qt / Qt designer form class.
2. Add X pages/widgets to the stackedWidget. X is the number of views You created
3. Promote each widget to be your custom designed page (right click in the objects tree on the right and choose promote widget). In field "promoted class name enter" enter the name of your cutom creacted page.

This should get you starded. I hope it solves Your problem. Ofcourse You have to design each view.

Comment: Hey thanks for the tip! I ended up doing it all through script without creating seperate classes which was nice.  I converted designer ui file into .py and had a read through that which helped heaps. In the end it was just me not being very clever with my layout stuff. But anyway finally figured out how to put a widget with its own gridLayout inside the master gridLayout etc. And it worked fine! Man so much easier creating UI's when you break it up into sections like that!

Comment: these 2 sites were quite useful: http://zetcode.com/tutorials/pyqt4/layoutmanagement/

Comment: It would be great if QtCreator supproted Python also :)